# How much wood can the average person expect to chop in a day?

Tags: technique, firewood

Winter is coming. I need lots of wood to keep warm. I know there are many variables involved but I would like to get a rough estimate of what one can expect to chop in a day.

**Assumptions**

- Average build, average height
- 20 - 30 yrs old
- Not an athlete but in good condition
- Tools: Splitting Axe, splitting wedge, maul, 20" chainsaw
- There is an area already set up for stacking the chopped wood
- Outside temperature is 70-80 F
- The wood is hardwood (oak/maple), not fully seasoned
- 8 hours to work (less if you don't think this is realistic), including breaks if need

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Back in the day, I fit the criteria in the question.

Assuming the wood is down and has been seasoned. One [Cord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cord_(unit)) (128 cubic feet or 3.62 m³) a day is easy.  I used to cut, split and load into the truck in the morning, sell it later in the day and stack it at the buyer's house. Do over next day.

2 or 3 cords a day should be reasonable production for cut, split, haul and stack. As it is unlikely that you need more then 10 cords for a season.  Doing a cord per morning, with other chores in the afternoon would be my choice.

If the wood is green (*been down for less then 6-12 months*) it is harder to split, may be twice as heavy, and provides significantly less heat. Not only will you have to work 2 or 3 times harder to stack each cord, you will need more cords to get you through the winter.

Related

- [How to stack wood](/a/13346)
- [What is the energy difference between green and seasoned fire wood?](/q/13756)

Comment: When fires were still permitted in my city, I found there were some woods that split easier when wet.  Pine was easier split dry, but I had rounds of something (maybe blue gum? it was 10 years ago) that dried tough.

Comment: @njzk2 10 cords of wood is the same as 26.25 steres.

Comment: I have update the answer with a link to Wikipedia about the volume of a US cord 128 cubic feet (3.62 m3)

Comment: @Sue Here is a possible photo from wiki (marked public domain) https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/Cord_of_wood.jpg A cord is generally defined in the US as a fixed volume of tightly stacked wood.

Answer (score 6):

Let's elaborate on this shall we?

A cord of wood is 4ft wide x 4 ft high x 8 feet long.

At 53 years old. Swinging an 8lb wedge, between bucking, splitting and stacking.

If I haul a lot of butt, a full cord is possible, but, not practical. Working by yourself that hard day in and day out, is why the logging industry is the most dangerous job on the planet. It's great to brag about how much wood you can get, but, bragging rights mean nothing when you're dead.

Take your time, stay safe, you are in no competition with anyone but yourself. Don't hold yourself to a standard you can't live up to, or you end up trying to hard to live up to a standard that literally no one else does.

The other thing is?

Stop relying on the internet to provide you with that standard. Go at your own pace and you will see that you will naturally demand more from yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean "chop" no one chops wood anymore. If the timber is already down you should be able to cut 18 inch lengths and split ( with a wood splitter) two face cord in 5 hours, that doesn't include stacking. I saw a post saying you need 10 cord for a winter. That's ridiculous. I burn 10 to 12 face cord a year, that's 3.5 to 4 cords. Of course that's in a boxwood airtight stove. If your burning in an outdoor burner, you could burn up to 7 or 8 cords.

I saw a post saying you could cut stack split and haul 2 or 3 cords in a day, or a cord each morning.  Not possible.  You be doing good to cut and split 3 face cord in 5 hours, that's 1 cord.  Add 20 minutes a face cord for stacking,  or 1 hour a cord.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please add whether you split wood yourself and if so, whether you are strong and experienced or someone who hardly ever splits wood and never have done it for commercial reasons. That does make a difference in what you can expect to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on alot of different factors. I cut between 15 and 30 cord a year so Im not new to the subject. On average one man working at a brisk pace can split, with a splitter, and stack approximately one cord of wood a day. This doesn't include driving to the woods and cutting the tree up and hauling it home. In that case, depending on how far away it is you can plan on half a cord. Keep in mind that it takes 3 face cord, (16 - 18" pieces in a row 8' long stacked 4' high.), to make one cord.
Please keep in mind that unless you are conditioned for this type of work, don't overdo it. It is very physical work and it will remind you of that the following morning.
Enjoy the workout my friend.